# Relational operator overloading for enum class

Tags: c++, visual-c++, enums, overloading

I got a problem while trying to overloading a less than operator for a enum class for experimental purpose, but surprisingly it only works for unary operators i.e. ++. The compiler complaints for ambiguity:

```
enum class Fruit
{
    apple,
    banana,
    orange,
    pineapple,
    lemon,
};

bool operator<(Fruit l, Fruit r) 
{
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    Fruit f = Fruit::banana;
    Fruit a = Fruit::apple;
    std::cout << (a < f);
}
```

Compiler obviously found another less than operator in global scope, but why it would not take the overloaded one for it's an exact match?

Comment: I have also tried operator<(const Fruit& l, const Fruit& r) but got the same result.

Comment: I don't get your concern. Your [operator is actually called](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c3f8b15987049420)?

Comment: Works for me. http://ideone.com/GO6HWR.

Comment: both gcc 4.9 and msvc 2015 has the error:  error C2593: 'operator <' is ambiguous

Comment: Are you compiling your program as a C++11 program? For `gcc`, you will need to to use `-std=c++11` in the command line. I don't know how one would enable C++11 features in VS2015.

Comment: Yes -std=c++14 is used for gcc.

Comment: Sorry my bad, it did work for gcc, but not MSVC.

Answer (score 4):

It's a Visual C++ compiler bug which has been open since 2010 and which Microsoft apparently won't fix anytime soon.

See [Visual Studio bug 529700](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/529700/enum-operator-overloading-broken):

> I can confirm that this is a bug with Visual C++. Unfortunately it
>   does not meet the triage bar for the current release of Visual C++ -
>   but we will keep the issue in our database and we will look at it
>   again during the development phase of a future release of Visual C++.

---

A good workaround depends on what you are trying to achieve, exactly. For example, if you want to put your `Fruit` into a standard container class like `std::map` or `std::set`, you might want to consider specialising `std::less`:

```
namespace std
{
    template<>
    struct less<Fruit>
    {
        bool operator()(Fruit const& lhs, Fruit const& rhs) const
        {
            // your comparison logic
        }
    };
}

std::set<Fruit> s;
```

Or you define a functor class for this purpose:

```
struct FruitComparison
{
    bool operator()(Fruit const& lhs, Fruit const& rhs) const
    {
        // your comparison logic
    }
};

std::set<Fruit, FruitComparison> s;
```

If you need the comparison for an algorithm, then you might want to use a lambda:

```
std::vector<Fruit> v;
std::sort(begin(v), end(v), [](Fruit const& lhs, Fruit const& rhs)
{
    // your comparison logic
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround (in addition to what [Christian Hackl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38036610/3697939) described), that worked for me:

1) Put your operator under a namespace (in ma case - same namespace as original enum):

```cpp
namespace App
{
    enum class Fruit
    {
        apple,
        banana,
        // ...
    };

    bool operator<(Fruit l, Fruit r) 
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

2) Call `operator<` by full name, including namespace:

```cpp
namespace App
{
    void foo()
    {
        Fruit f = Fruit::banana;
        Fruit a = Fruit::apple;

        std::cout << App::operator<(a, f);
    }
}

int main()
{
    App::foo();
}
```